# Siteminder Fcc attribute not read in seperate javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, siteminder

I have a login.fcc page which I want to modularize into Javascript,CSS & HTML modules so that it can be maintained easily.
As you know in Siteminder FCC pages we have number of Attributes which we can access and write code accordingly.
When I try to pull this $$smauthreason$$ in seperate js file I am not able to access the attribute value.(this value shd be set by siteminder when this fcc page is called).

Any ideas why I am not able to put this javascript code in seperate js file?

Comment: Questions that include SSCCE code, http://sscce.org/, are much easier to answer for people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated before, the FCC file is the only file processed by the web agent,so you can't do the variable substitution in other files.

I think probably what i'd suggest is binding all the variables to 'global' javascript variables in your fcc file.  This would allow you to import javascript source files into the HTML that would have access to the variables, but as javascript variables and not $$USER$$,etc type variables.

The other thing you might play with (and I have not done this) is to try server side includes if you're using apache.  If the server side includes are processed BEFORE the fcc handler, then you might be able to modularize more.

Answer (score 1):

SiteMinder web agent will only serve .fcc files.  If you have another file (.js) you must host it on another server instance, but you will not be able to access the SM attributes from it.

Comment: You can serve any file from the same server instance.  But you are correct that the web agent will not process them and thus you won't get access to them.